# Rendering decals on 3d meshes

Tags: opengl, 3d, rendering, direct3d, decal

As in question, what are the best techniques for rendering lots (lots!) of decals on multiple meshes (which can move) and on terrain?

Comment: Are you doing something along the lines of massive blood explosions which need to goop onto everything? Do your decals have to be textures or can they be procedurally generated? Will the decals be placed randomly on the characters or are they like clothing labels and insignia?

Comment: What I'd like to have:
1. blood decals, which spread over everyting, 
2. bullet decals (holes in the walls, etc)
3. and some static decals, like graffiti on walls, or tattoo on characters arm.
But most problematic for me is first case, and last case (that with tattoo: generate separate texture for every character? or keep it as separate mesh and bind to skeleton? etc etc)

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're after, but the technique that comes to mind when you say "lots of decals on terrain" is [Texture Bombing](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch20.html)